# replace string in all files in a folder

Tags: python-3.x

can't figure out why this doesn't work, it just outputs a bunch of "skipping files"

I'm trying to replace =+ with = in all files in a folder

```
import os

directory_path=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

files = os.listdir(directory_path)

for each_file in files:
    with open(os.path.join(directory_path, each_file), 'r+') as file:
        file.replace('=+', '=')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe you have been using a different encoding from 'utf-8', can you check for this one:

```
for each_file in files:
    with open(os.path.join(directory_path, each_file), mode='r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as file:
        filedata = file.read()

    filedata = filedata.replace('=+', '=')

    with open(os.path.join(directory_path, each_file), mode='w', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as file:
        file.write(filedata)
```

Let me know if this works now.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matt/Documents/Commands/data.py", line 56, in <module>
    file.read().replace('=+', '=')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 1128: invalid start byte

Comment: I believe the error comes from not using 'utf-8', Can you check for the revised answer above?

Comment: Ok, that means the encoding 'ISO-8859-1' is the correct one, you can try the above now: This should work. Let me know if you get any errors.